# How to make SQLAlchemy not communicate with database before commit?

Tags: python, postgresql, performance, sqlalchemy, orm

I noticed that SQLAlchemy will send SQL to database and wait for result with each `session.execute()` even if autoflush is disabled.

I have quite high ping to database, so I would like to make SQLAlchemy wait until `session.commit()` before it sends anything to database. It is also ok if SQLAlchemy would send SQL but not wait for response from database.

I understand that if error would happen then SQLAlchemy would be able to notify about it only after `session.commit()`.

```py
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, text
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from timeit import default_timer as timer

Base = declarative_base()
metadata = Base.metadata

tmp_table = Table(
    'table_with_numbers', metadata,
    Column('some_number', Integer, nullable=False),
)

engine=create_engine('postgresql://aaa:bbb@example.com:5432/ccc')

session=sessionmaker(bind=engine, autoflush=False)
with session() as s:

    t1=timer()
    sql = """CREATE TEMP TABLE table_with_numbers
                    (some_number Integer) ON COMMIT DROP;"""
    s.execute(text(sql))
    t2=timer()
    print(f"Time taken t2-t1: {t2-t1}s")


    s.execute(tmp_table.insert(), [
        {'some_number':1},
        {'some_number':2},
        {'some_number':3},
    ])
    t3=timer()
    print(f"Time taken t3-t2: {t3-t2}s")


    s.commit()
    t4=timer()
    print(f"Time taken t4-t3: {t4-t3}s")
```

result:

```
Time taken t2-t1: 0.2557111999922199s
Time taken t3-t2: 0.12612390000140294s
Time taken t4-t3: 0.12949950000620447s
```

desired result (more or less):

```
Time taken t2-t1: 0.0001s
Time taken t3-t2: 0.0001s
Time taken t4-t3: 0.2557111999922199s
```